# multiplying each element of one array by all the elements of a second array

Tags: c#

I am having a difficult time multiplying elements that are in two array's.

```
    int[] firstArray = { 1,2,3,4 };
    int[] secondArray = { 10,20,30,40 };
```

I need to multiply the first element of the "firstArray" by each of the elements in the "secondArray". Then take the second element of the "firstArray" by each of the elements in the "secondArray", and so on until i have multiplied all of the elements in the first array by each of the elements in the second array.

so far I have figured out how to get the first element to do this by building a 3rd array

```
    int[] thirdArray = [4]

    for (int counter = 0; counter < thirdArray.Length; counter ++)
    thirdArray[counter] = firstArray[counter] * secondArray[counter];
    console.WriteLine(thirdArray[counter]);
```

This just takes the elements of the first array and directly multiply across to the second element. I should have 16 int results but if I change the thirdArray to [16] there is a out of range exception.
if you can help it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative approach, you could use [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397926.aspx) for this:

```
var query = from x in firstArray
            from y in secondArray
            select x * y;

int[] thirdArray = query.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe this will achieve what you are looking for:

```
int[] thirdArray = new int[16];

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        thirdArray[i * 4 + j] = firstArray[i] * secondArray[j];
```

Comment: This helped a lot, it was just enough to jump start my brain in the right direction

Comment: Great news! Glad I could help and you got your solution.

Answer (score 1):

This should solve your problem:

```
int[] firstArray = { 1,2,3,4 };
  int[] secondArray = { 10,20,30,40 };
    int[] thirdArray = new int[firstArray.Length*secondArray.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < firstArray.Length; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < secondArray.Length; j++)
    {
        thirdArray[i*firstArray.Length + j] = firstArray[i] * secondArray[j];
        Console.WriteLine(thirdArray[i*firstArray.Length + j]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Heck, you can even do away with the braces to denote scope, since there's only one operation in the scope of each iteration:

```
int[] firstArray = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
int[] secondArray = { 10, 20, 30, 40 };
for (int i = 0; i < firstArray.Length; i++ )
    foreach (int second in secondArray)
        firstArray[i] *= second;
```

Answer (score 0):

Done in a single line, using LINQ:

```
var allMultiples = firstArray.SelectMany(a => secondArray.Select(b => a * b));
```